# special character in sql for h2 database

Tags: sql, special-characters, h2

I use the query below:

```
update ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS 
   set EXTERNAL_ID = 'username:vietnt' 
 where ACCOUNT_ID='1000000' 
   and EMAIL_ADDRESS='NULL'
```

It shows the error:

```
ERROR: Column "USERNAME" not found; SQL statement:
update ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS set EXTERNAL_ID=username:vietnt where ACCOUNT_ID=1000000 and EMAIL_ADDRESS=NULL [42122-147]
```

I use back slash \, then, the query become:

```
update ACCOUNT_EXTERNAL_IDS 
   set EXTERNAL_ID = 'username\:vietnt' 
 where ACCOUNT_ID = '1000000' 
   and EMAIL_ADDRESS='NULL'
```

The error is the same.

Comment: What tool are you using to send the sql to the db?

Comment: It should be `EMAIL_ADDRESS IS NULL` unless you really store the character string `NULL` in your email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

The escape character '\' resolve the problem.

The issue I encounter is I use ssh connect. So, it eliminates the character '\'